# How to prevent Domain Users group from being added to local Users group

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I do not want the Domain Users group to be automatically added to the local "Users" group when a computer joins the domain, but am struggling with finding how to prevent this.

In the default domain policy under User Configuration - Preferenaces - Control Panel Settings - Local Users and Groups, I added a group called "Users" with an entry "domain\Domain Users" with action of "Remove", but that did not do anything.

Any suggestions?  If it matters, the domain and forest functional levels are 2012 R2.

Comment: Could you please fill us in on *why* you're trying to do this? What problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Because this is being deployed for a multi-tennant environment and I don't want one tennant from having even user level access to another's server.  So I want to remove any automatic user or group assignments and explicitly grant the ones that I do want.

Comment: Are you able to update the original post with a screenshot of the 'Users (built-in) Properties' screen where you configured this GPO?  Setting this GPO update correctly should do what you're trying.  If you could update the post, I can see how you've configured this.